# clip to show how configure and use GCDwebserver

Tags: gcdwebserver

i want to conference about GCD Webserver to my classmates, but i don`t know how to configure and use it, and i don`t have mac laptop to test, so i need a good tutorial clip about this, searching a lot but could not find anything , every thing is just about GCD not GCDWebserver

Answer (score 1):

GCDWebServer is intended to be used by developers who already know about Objective-C and the Mac / iOS environment. The [official README](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer/blob/master/README.md) is the best place to start from. Then open the Xcode project and just look at the code for the apps.

There is no video tutorial or blog tutorial that I know of.

Comment: re Objective-C, as of late 2017, GCDWebServer is very Swift compatible. I don't think one needs to know Objective-C to use it at this point if one knows Swift.